riverpod_generator does not recognize types generated by Drift as parameters
pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
    ...
    drift: ^2.20.2
    drift_flutter: ^0.1.0
    flutter_riverpod: ^2.5.1

dev_dependencies:
    ...
    drift_dev: ^2.20.3
    riverpod_generator: ^2.3.3
    build_runner: ^2.4.12

database.dart
part 'database.g.dart';

class TodoItems extends Table {
  TextColumn get id => text()();

  TextColumn get title => text()();

  TextColumn get content => text().nullable()();

  @override
  Set<Column<Object>>? get primaryKey => {id};
}

@DriftDatabase(tables: [TodoItems])
class AppDatabase extends _$AppDatabase {
    ...
}

providers.dart
/// add todo item
/// [TodoItem] generated by drift
@riverpod
Future<void> addTodo(AddTodoRef ref, TodoItem todo) async {

}

Then run dart run build_runner watch -d will generate database.g.dart and providers.g.dart
The problem is
providers.g.dart will define the TodoItem type in database.g.dart as InvalidType, not TodoItem

How can providers.g.dart define TodoItem correctly?
Is there any way to make Drift's code generator execute before Riverpod's code generator?

It looks like you're trying to make it into a family key, and it doesn't know that type as a family key.  Perhaps you're missing an import, or the drift generation is happening after the riverpod generation?

Wait, why are you trying to create an addTodoProvider?

@RandalSchwartz The addTodoProvider method is created to insert data into the database. In my project, a row of data contains many attributes. I don’t want to pass the attributes one by one as parameters. I want to pass them directly through objects.

Yes, that would be a method on a class, not a provider.

I bet order in which builders called matters here. Usually one can manage it with runs_before or something in builder's configuration, but I couldn't make it work with drift+riverpod specifically.

@Sameri11 I created a new build.yaml and used runs_before in it to let drift generate code before riverpod, but it didn't work.
